# Шаблон Twig не переопределяет родителя

Tags: symfony, twig

Подскажите, пожалуйста, я настолько долблюсь в глаза и не могу выполнить простейшие шаги из официальной документации или я даже не знаю. Дочерний Twig не переопределяет родителя и не выводит свой контент, ощущение, что он даже не подключен, хотя он явно подключен.

```
//templates/base.html.twig

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>
            {% block title %}base
            {% endblock %}
        </title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
            base content
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

```
//templates/blocks/index.html.twig

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}header
            {% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <h1>header content</h1>
 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: что выводится в аутпуте?

Comment: как настроен симфони?

Comment: @МихаилРебров, на счёт настройки немного не понимаю, установлен через composer, как указанно в документации, всё выполнял пошагово, проблему пока что решаю с помощью `{@include twig_name}`, но хотелось бы через наследование)